# Close other open divs on click

Tags: jquery, hide, jquery-animate, html

I've got several divs hidden in the overflow of a parent and have them animating up into view on click of the corresponding nav menu item, but I want each div to return to its original position once another one is opened. Each div and nav item has a separate corresponding id.

Code is below.

I know there's plenty of similar issues on here already, but am fairly new to Jquery so any help would be great.

```
var sipPos = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#news").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#tab1").animate({ bottom: sipPos }, 600, 'linear', function() {
        if(sipPos == 0) { sipPos = -800;}
        else { sipPos = 0; }
    });
});
});
```

*Sorry html follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<div id="content">


<nav><strong>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="News" id="news">NEWS  <span class="slash">//</span>         </a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Dates" id="dates">LIVE DATES  <span    class="slash">//</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Media" id="media">MEDIA  <span class="slash">//</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Band" id="band">BAND  <span class="slash">//</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Community" id="community">COMMUNITY <span class="slash">//</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Merchandise" id="merch">MERCHANDISE <span class="slash">//</span></a></li>
</ul></strong>
</nav>

<div id="tab1">
</div>

<div id="tab2">
</div>

<div id="tab3">
</div>

<div id="tab4">
</div>

<div id="tab5">
</div>

</div>
```

Edit

Have given all the nav links a class of tab and the divs a class of slide.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$(".slide");
lastMove = 0;
$(".tab").click(function() { 
    divIndex = $(this).index(); // this index relates to the ordered div list
    if (lastMove.length > 0) {
        $(lastMove).animate({"bottom": "-=800px"}, "slow");

    }
    lastMove = $(".slide:eq("+divIndex+")");
    $(lastMove).animate({"bottom": "+=800px"}, "slow"); 
});
});
```

The first tab is now opening for every nav item as opposed to each corresponding div, index problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm,

Do you mean something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/NWMZJ/1/

```
//css
.moveDiv {
position:absolute;
left:50px;
top:50px;
    display: block;

}

<div class="moveDiv" id="1">content1content1content1</div>
<div class="moveDiv" id="2">content2content2content2</div>

    $(document).ready(function() { 
    lastMove = 0;
    $(".moveDiv").click(function() { 
        if (lastMove.length > 0) {
            $(lastMove).animate({"left": "-=200px", "top": "-=200px"}, "slow");
        }
        lastMove = $(this);
        $(lastMove ).animate({"left": "+=200px", "top": "+=200px"}, "slow"); 
    });
});
```

Bassicaly what I belive you are asking is how you move a div when you click it to a preset co-ordinate, and then when you click another div move the moved one back and place the new one in place.

Something to be aware off is that in CSS, a DIV is default possition: Static when it is not set, thus you must declare it as absolute or it will not function.

I have attempted your comment @ jsfiddle.net/NWMZJ/3

The list's arrangement links in unison with the div arrangement, so that when you select class 2, it selects the second div to show.

////////

Can you confirm you have put the class's onto the html tags?

```
       <nav><strong> <ul>     
            <li class="tab"><a href="#" title="News" id="news">NEWS  <span class="slash">//</span>         </a></li>     
            <li class="tab"><a href="#" title="Dates" id="dates">LIVE DATES  <span    class="slash">//</span></a></li>     
            <li class="tab"><a href="#" title="Media" id="media">MEDIA  <span class="slash">//</span></a></li>     
            <li class="tab"><a href="#" title="Band" id="band">BAND  <span class="slash">//</span></a></li>     
            <li class="tab"><a href="#" title="Community" id="community">COMMUNITY <span class="slash">//</span></a></li>     
            <li class="tab"><a href="#" title="Merchandise" id="merch">MERCHANDISE <span class="slash">//</span></a></li> </ul></strong> </nav>  

           <div class="slide" id="tab1"> NEWS</div>
          <div class="slide" id="tab2"> DATES</div>
          <div class="slide" id="tab3">MEDIA</div> 
         <div class="slide" id="tab4"> BAND</div>  

<div class="slide" id="tab5"> COMMUNITY</div> 
<div class="slide" id="tab6"> MERCHANDISE </div>
```

Comment: Yeah that's basically it, but can I assign that class to a nav list item so that triggers the click function? sorry, new at this.

Comment: @John Hmm seems I was a little over-eager, I've removed the fade out/in as the divs are hidden in the overflow. The links now only open the first tab now, although they do move it down and back up on each click so I think the problem is in the index. I've edited ques above.

Comment: see my edit, it sounds like you have not appended the class tags onto the html tags, without these the indexing will not work

Answer (score 0):

i'd give the divs a class 'tab'. Then you could write:

```
$("#tab1").animate({ bottom: sipPos }, 600, 'linear', function() {
   if(sipPos == 0) { sipPos = -800;}
   else { sipPos = 0; }
});

$(".tab:not(#tab1)").animate({ bottom: 0}); //.....
```

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Comment: Cheers but this seems to open then instantly close the next div on click whilst leaving the original open